# How to do FFT convolve? How to do normalization?

Tags: numpy, fft, convolution, fftw

In Python, we can do a convolution by numpy.fft. For example, if we try to calculate gravitational lensing signal of the SIS model, we could define $\kappa$ as
$\kappa = \frac{\theta_{\rm E}}{2|\theta|}$,
then we can calculate deflection angle $\alpha$ by a convolution as $\alpha = \frac{1}{\pi} \int d\theta'^2 \kappa(\theta) \frac{\theta-\theta'}{|\theta-\theta'|}$ .  Theoretically,  deflection is $\alpha(\theta) = \theta_{\rm E}\frac{\theta}{|\theta|}$.  But when I try to calculate that by numpy.fft, I am puzzled by some factors of normalization. For example,

```
npix   = 2048        #mesh grid number
thetaE = 0.5         #a constant
dtheta = thetaE/10   #grid resolution
theta_x, theta_y, theta = mesh_theta(npix, dtheta)  #assign grid position for calculation, theta will be an array of 2048*2048

kappa = thetaE/2./theta   #define kappa mesh, 2048*2048
kern_alpha_x, kern_alpha_y = kernal_alpha(theta_x, theta_y)    #define kernal mesh, 2048*2048

###zero padding should be used###

kappa_fft = np.fft.fft2(kappa)
kern_alpha_x_fft = np.fft.fft2(kern_alpha_x)
kern_alpha_y_fft = np.fft.fft2(kern_alpha_y)

alpha_x = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(kappa_fft*kern_alpha_x_fft)).real
alpha_y = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(kappa_fft*kern_alpha_y_fft)).real
```

As shown above,  $\alpha_{\rm x}$, $\alpha_{\rm y}$ could be calculated by convolution between $\kappa$ and $K_{\alpha_{\rm x}}$, $K_{\alpha_{\rm y}}$, which means deflection $|\alpha| = \sqrt{\alpha_{\rm x}^2+\alpha_{\rm y}^2}$. However, when I check the results from `alpha_x, alpha_y`, it seems there is a normalization should be multiplied. If I multiply a factor as `np.sqrt(alpha_x**2 + alpha_y**2)*dtheta*dtheta`, then the result seems to be right. I do not know should this normalization `dtheta*dtheta`must be used and why?  Thx.

Comment: [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated[/scipy.signal.convolve.html) let's you choose the convolution method in `{'auto', 'direct', 'fft'}`. You can also check which method will (probably) be the fastest using the [`scipy.signal.choose_conv_method`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.choose_conv_method.html#scipy.signal.choose_conv_method).

Comment: Exactly. scipy.convolve can be used directly to calculate convolution and, in fact, I have compared that with fft manually. However, the normalization should also be multiplied manually after convolution.

Comment: np.fft.fft2 has `norm` keyword parameter, so all normalization should be handled for you. It seems to me that either the convolution kernel or signal data are not properly normalized. It's hard to parse latex, as it's not formatted for me for some reason.